# Cannot get program to print to command line or report file

Tags: java

I have a program here that compiles but I cannot get it to print to the command line or a report file.  Any assistance is appreciated. Here is the error that I get:

Error: Main method not found in class Township, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
Press any key to continue . .

```
    import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


//Township class
class Township
{
   //instance variables
   String name;
   int households;
   int bicycles;
   double average;
   String tier;
   double funding;

   //constructor
   public Township(String name, int households, int bicycles)
   {
       this.name = name;
       this.households = households;
       this.bicycles = bicycles;
   }
   //calculate average bikes per household
   public void AverageBikes()
   {
       average = (double)bicycles/households;
   }
   //calculate the funding
   public void Funding()
   {
       if(average>=3.0) funding = 50000.00;
       else if(average>=2.0) funding = 40000.00;
       else if(average>=1.0) funding = 30000.00;
       else if(average>=0.5) funding = 20000.00;
       else funding = 0.00;
   }
   //calculate the tier
   public void Tier()
   {
       if(average>=3.0) tier = "One";
       else if(average>=2.0) tier = "Two";
       else if(average>=1.0) tier = "Three";
       else if(average>=0.5) tier = "Four";
       else tier = "Five";
   }
   //sort the townships in alphabetical order by township name
   public static void sort(Township t[], int n)
   {
       for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++){
           for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++){
               if(t[i].name.compareTo(t[j].name) > 0){
                   Township tmp = t[i];
                   t[i] = t[j];
                   t[j] = tmp;
               }
           }
       }
   }
}

//Driver class
class Driver
{
   //method to print the report
   public static void printReport(Township t[], int n)
   {
       //sort the list
       Township.sort(t, n);

       System.out.println ("Township           Number       Bicycles   Average Bikes   Proposed       Tier");
       System.out.println ("Name               Households   reported   Per household   Funding           Designation");

       //print the report
       for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
       {
           System.out.printf ("%-20s%-12d%-12d%-16.2f%-16.2f%s\n", t[i].name, t[i].households,
               t[i].bicycles, t[i].average, t[i].funding, t[i].tier);
       }
   }
   //method to get input from user
   public static Township getInput(Scanner sc)
   {
       System.out.print ("Enter the name of Township: ");
       String name = sc.nextLine();
       System.out.print ("Enter the number households: ");
       int household = sc.nextInt();
       System.out.print ("Enter the bicycles reported: ");
       int bicycles = sc.nextInt();

       Township town = new Township(name, household, bicycles);
       town.AverageBikes();
       town.Funding();
       town.Tier();

       return town;
   }
   //method to get input from file
   public static int readFile(Township town[]) throws IOException
   {
       //open the file
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("town.txt"));

       int i=0;
       while(sc.hasNext())
       {
           String name = sc.nextLine();
           int household = sc.nextInt();
           sc.nextLine();
           int bicycles = sc.nextInt();
           sc.nextLine();

           town[i] = new Township(name, household, bicycles);
           town[i].AverageBikes();
           town[i].Funding();
           town[i].Tier();
           i++;     
       }
       return i;
   }

   //method to write the report to the file
   public static void writeFile(Township t[], int n) throws IOException
   {
       //sort the list
       Township.sort(t, n);

       FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("report.txt");
       PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter(writer);


       pout.printf ("Township           Number       Bicycles   Average Bikes   Proposed       Tier\n");
       pout.printf ("Name               Households   reported   Per household   Funding           Designation\n");

       for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
       {
           pout.printf ("%-20s%-12d%-12d%-16.2f%-16.2f%s\n", t[i].name, t[i].households,
               t[i].bicycles, t[i].average, t[i].funding, t[i].tier);
       }
       pout.close();
   }

   //main method
   public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
   {
       //create an instance of Scanner class
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       //create an array of Townships
       Township town[] = new Township[10];

       int i= readFile(town);

       //processing
       while(true)
       {
           //menu
           System.out.println ("1. Input\n2. Report\n3. Exit");
           //prompt to enter a choice
           System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
           int n = sc.nextInt();

           switch(n)
           {
               case 1:
                   //get input from user
                   town[i] = getInput(sc);
                   i++;
                   break;
               case 2:
                   //print the report
                   printReport(town, i);
                   break;
               case 3:
                   //write to file
                   writeFile(town, i);
                   System.out.println ("Goodbye!");
                   return;
           }
       }      
   }
}
```

---

## EDIT

I updated the error and some code thanks to the responses.

Here is the new error that I get:

> Error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException at
>   java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939) at
>   java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594) at
>   java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258) at
>   java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212) at
>   Township.readFile(Township.java:143) at
>   Township.main(Township.java:20)

Code:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

//Township class
public class Township{
   //instance variables
   String name;
   int households;
   int bicycles;
   double average;
   String tier;
   double funding;
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{
       //create an instance of Scanner class
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       //create an array of Townships
       Township town[] = new Township[10];

       int i= readFile(town);

       //processing
       while(true)
       {
           //menu
           System.out.println ("1. Input\n2. Report\n3. Exit");
           //prompt to enter a choice
           System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
           int n = sc.nextInt();

           switch(n)
           {
               case 1:
                   //get input from user
                   town[i] = getInput(sc);
                   i++;
                   break;
               case 2:
                   //print the report
                   printReport(town, i);
                   break;
               case 3:
                   //write to file
                   writeFile(town, i);
                   System.out.println ("Goodbye!");
                   return;
           }
       }
   }
//==================================================================
   //constructor
   public Township(String name, int households, int bicycles)
   {
       this.name = name;
       this.households = households;
       this.bicycles = bicycles;
   }
   //calculate average bikes per household
   public void AverageBikes()
   {
       average = (double)bicycles/households;
   }
   //calculate the funding
   public void Funding()
   {
       if(average>=3.0) funding = 50000.00;
       else if(average>=2.0) funding = 40000.00;
       else if(average>=1.0) funding = 30000.00;
       else if(average>=0.5) funding = 20000.00;
       else funding = 0.00;
   }
   //calculate the tier
//==================================================================
   public void Tier()
   {
       if(average>=3.0) tier = "One";
       else if(average>=2.0) tier = "Two";
       else if(average>=1.0) tier = "Three";
       else if(average>=0.5) tier = "Four";
       else tier = "Five";
   }
   //sort the townships in alphabetical order by township name
   public static void sort(Township t[], int n)
   {
       for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++){
           for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++){
               if(t[i].name.compareTo(t[j].name) > 0){
                   Township tmp = t[i];
                   t[i] = t[j];
                   t[j] = tmp;
               }
           }
       }
   }
//==================================================================
   //method to print the report
   public static void printReport(Township t[], int n)
   {
       //sort the list
       Township.sort(t, n);

       System.out.println ("Township           Number       Bicycles   Average Bikes   Proposed       Tier");
       System.out.println ("Name               Households   reported   Per household   Funding           Designation");

       //print the report
       for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
       {
           System.out.printf ("%-20s%-12d%-12d%-16.2f%-16.2f%s\n", t[i].name, t[i].households,
               t[i].bicycles, t[i].average, t[i].funding, t[i].tier);
       }
   }
//==================================================================
   //method to get input from user
   public static Township getInput(Scanner sc)
   {
       System.out.print ("Enter the name of Township: ");
       String name = sc.nextLine();
       System.out.print ("Enter the number households: ");
       int household = sc.nextInt();
       System.out.print ("Enter the bicycles reported: ");
       int bicycles = sc.nextInt();

       Township town = new Township(name, household, bicycles);
       town.AverageBikes();
       town.Funding();
       town.Tier();

       return town;
   }
//==================================================================
   //method to get input from file
   public static int readFile(Township town[]) throws IOException
   {
       //open the file
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("bicycledata.txt"));

       int i=0;
       while(sc.hasNext())
       {
           String name = sc.nextLine();
           int households = sc.nextInt();
           sc.nextLine();
           int bicycles = sc.nextInt();
           sc.nextLine();

           town[i] = new Township(name, households, bicycles);
           town[i].AverageBikes();
           town[i].Funding();
           town[i].Tier();
           i++;
       }
       return i;
   }
//==================================================================
   //method to write the report to the file
   public static void writeFile(Township t[], int n) throws IOException{
       //sort the list
       Township.sort(t, n);

       FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("report.txt");
       PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter(writer);


       pout.printf ("Township           Number       Bicycles   Average Bikes   Proposed       Tier\n");
       pout.printf ("Name               Households   reported   Per household   Funding           Designation\n");

       for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
       {
           pout.printf ("%-20s%-12d%-12d%-16.2f%-16.2f%s\n", t[i].name, t[i].households,
               t[i].bicycles, t[i].average, t[i].funding, t[i].tier);
       }
       pout.close();
   }//end method
}//end class
```

Comment: You should not edit a question such that it invalidates an answer. Your edit invalidates @Alberto Ursino 's answer. Please change your question so that the changes are obviously as a result of his answer.

Comment: In Township.Tier, your if statements all are ended by semicolons, which causes the else statements to be incorrect.

Comment: I tried removing the semicolons and even adding brackets. Neither will compile without the semicolons.

Comment: I use braces for all if-statements even when it isn't required. This prevents one small source of bugs. With the semicolons as you have them, the if-statements are wrong. Without braces, only the final else statement requires a semicolon.

Comment: C:\Users\17329\Documents\New folder\Township.java:78: error: ';' expected
       if(average>=3.0) tier = "One"


This repeats for each line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Township {
    //instance variables
    String name;
    int households;
    int bicycles;
    double average;
    String tier;
    double funding;

    //constructor
    public Township(String name, int households, int bicycles) {
        this.name = name;
        this.households = households;
        this.bicycles = bicycles;
    }

    // Rest of Township class code...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Do things...
    }
}
```

Take a look to this: [Essentials](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/prog-140388.html)

> Every application needs one class with a main method. This class is
>   the entry point for the program, and is the class name passed to the
>   java interpreter command to run the application.

---

`IOException` is thrown to you for another reason. The answer to your question has been given.

Comment: It is still not liking it.  It's saying that int i= readFile(town); is one of the issues

Answer (score -1):

I think you are compiling class Township which do not have main() method. You should compile Driver class because class Driver has main() method and creating the object of class Township.

Comment: Hi. Edited, please see updates. getting IOException errors still.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
        at Township.readFile(Township.java:143)
        at Township.main(Township.java:20)
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: There is an error in your readFile() method in reading the file because the input which are given is not matched with the variable which is accepting

Comment: public static int readFile(Township town[]) throws IOException{
       
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("bicycledata.txt"));


       int i=0;
       while(sc.hasNext())
       {
           String name = sc.nextLine();
           int households = sc.nextInt();
           sc.nextLine();
           int bicycles = sc.nextInt();
           sc.nextLine();

           town[i] = new Township(name, households, bicycles);
           town[i].AverageBikes();
           town[i].Funding();
           town[i].Tier();
           i++;
       }
       return i;
   }

Comment: This is the data file

Edison Township 10000 16700
South Amboy City 6500 19175
Cranbury Township 7500 6675
Woodbridge Township 12000 17400
Monroe Township 6230 22739
Metuchen Borough 4250 11942
East Brunswick Township 5225 16249
Piscataway Township 8125 26243
Jamesburg Borough 7000 3920
Old Bridge Township 11500 16675

Comment: You can and have to compile a class regardless of whether it has a `main` method or not. This answer, in general, is of rather poor quality. It is more a comment than a full answer that solves all issues of OP. Please read [answer] to see how you can improve it.